# Send Event from Native to Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, events, callback

I'm using an Ionic/Cordova plugin to watch a data set and want to call a function in my typescript class when the native api triggers an event. What I have so far is: (Typescript file)

```
this.platform.ready().then(() =>{
window.plugins.plugin.startFileWatch("Path", (success) =>{console.log("Succes")}, (error) => {Console.log("ERROR"}))
}
```

and then in java script from the plugin

```
startFileWatch: function( path, succesCB, errorCB){
  exec(succesCB, errorCB, "Class", "startFileWatch", [path]);
}
```

and in swift (though android solutions are welcome aswell):

```
    @objc(startFileWatch:)
    func startFileWatch(command:CDVInvokedUrlCommand){
           //bit pseudo here      
           something.addListener{
                self?.commandDelage.send(result, callbackID: command.callbackID)
}
    }
```

this however didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TS and JS script looks good. And what you are missing is that, you are not saving the callback for future triggers. To trigger a dynamic event from Native to TS, you need to have a listener which will actually register a callback in native layer. Then this callback is used to push event to TS layer.

```
    // Android

    protected static CallbackContext eventTriggerObj = null;
    .....
    .....

    private boolean registerForEvents ( final CallbackContext callbackContext )
    {
        eventTriggerObj = callbackContext;
        return true;
    }


  // iOS ( Obj C )

  @property ( nonatomic, retain ) NSString * eventTriggerObj ;  
  .....
  .....

  - ( void ) registerForEvents :( CDVInvokedUrlCommand * ) command
    {
        self.eventTriggerObj = command.callbackId;
        CDVPluginResult * pluginResult = [ CDVPluginResult 
             resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK ];
         [ pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:true ];
         [ self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult 
         callbackId:command.callbackId ];
    }

    // Swift Code (3+)
    private var eventTriggerObj : String

    void registerForEvent(command : CDVInvokedUrlCommand){
         self.eventTriggerObj = command.callbackId
         let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAs: ["Message"])
         pluginResult?.keepCallback = true
         self?.commandDelegate.send(pluginResult, callbackId: self?.eventTriggerObj)
    }
```

Now use the callback object **eventTriggerObj** to send the dynamic events to the TS Layer.

Comment: Thnx, do you have the Swift (3) code as well by any chance?

Comment: Nope. Have experimented only with Obj C. But from your above code, I could interpret that you need to store the 'command.callbackID' as a class variable to access it later when you want to send triggers to TS.